# No access to my own external hard drive?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, mount, sudo, root

I have only used my external hard drive once, wich was with my previous Ubuntu installation (11.04), on the same laptop. I have created 2 partitions, FAT32 and EXT4. Now I needed to get some data from my external hard drive and IT WOULD NOT LET ME. No matter what I do in Nautilus, it will not do a thing with it. It is NOT corrupted. When I do `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1` in a terminal, it said **Permissions denied**... (SO IT WON'T ALLOW ME TO ACCESS MY OWN DATA??). When mounting it as root, it works, but I don't want to. Things should simply work, normal users don't want to dive into a command line and go edit text files to do a simple action like mounting an external hard drive, and neither do I.
When mounting it as root, by the way, and running `sudo chown robin /media/sdb1` it even sais *Permission denied*, while I am running the command **as root!** Frankly, I'm getting sick of things like this.
Any way to fix this for once and forever? No solutions please that I'll have to apply every time I reinstall Ubuntu on my laptop or anything like that. I am a **user**, I want to **use**. Not dive into command lines and text files for the simplest possible actions.

--Edit--
Just to clarify, I've got no problems with typing a few commands in a terminal windows, as long as that solved the problem **permanently**. I don't want to have to go through a mess like this on every computer or every time I reinstall my OS.

Comment: What kind of external harddisk is this? USB disks will automatically mount when you connect it.

Comment: ... I dunno. Just a simple 2,5" USB3 external hard drive.

Comment: What happens when you connect it? It is supposed to be mounted automatically and become available in Nautilus.

Comment: ... That's the problem. It doesn't. I need root permissions to mount it.

Comment: What the... I just updated my system and the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating my system, the problem disappeared.